# Getting Error : 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Tags: python, if-statement, integer, do-while, isnumeric

I was writing a code to get a student grade point average but I got an error.
here is the piece of my code getting error :

```
scoreinput=input("Score lesson: ")
while True:
    if scoreinput.isnumeric():
        scoreinput=int(scoreinput)
        if scoreinput > 20:
            scoreinput = int(input("This number is too big. Try again: "))
        elif scoreinput < 0:
            scoreinput = int(input("This number is too low. Try again: "))
    else:
        print("please write number correctly...")
```

This is the output of this code which has got an error :

```
Score lesson: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\TEST PYTHON\test3.py", line 3, in <module>
    if scoreinput.isnumeric():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric
```

please help me. thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Possible causes are that you're running the code under 2.x, or that you have redefined `input` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is a positive number below 20, which is what you want to have, after `scoreinput=int(scoreinput)`
you have the number, but instead of doing something, you continue to the next iteration of the while loop. On the next iteration, `scoreinput` is an `int` and not `str` this is why you get an error. If `scoreinput` is in the correct range, you should use `break` to stop the loop.

Another problem occurs when the input is wrong. If the input is not a number, you are not getting a new input and will be stuck in an infinite loop. If the input is a number, but not between 0 to 20, you get new input and imminently cast it to `int`. If the input is not a number you will get an exception. If it is a number, it will fail as soon as you reach the next iteration since `scoreinput` should be `str` at the beginning of the iteration, but it will be `int`.

I would suggest you will use the following code:

```
while True:
    scoreinput=input("Score lesson: ")  # using input only one time at the beggining of the loop instead of input command for each case of bad input
    if scoreinput.isnumeric():
        scoreinput=int(scoreinput)
        if scoreinput > 20:
            print("This number is too big. Try again.")
        elif scoreinput < 0:
            print("This number is too low. Try again.")
        else:
            break  # input is valid
    else:
        print("please write number correctly...")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you write on the top: `scoreinput = int(input('Score lesson: '))` you won't have to verify if `scoreinput` is numeric or alphabetic.